# Typescript/Vue3 - Forced to use type 'any'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a composable function that returns an array of objects and a function that received a string and doesn't return anything.

The below code 'works' and doesn't throw any errors.

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";

interface RouterHelper {
    children: any;
    getChildrenOf: (name: string) => void;
}

export const routerHelper = (): RouterHelper => {
    const route = useRoute();
    const children = ref();

    const getChildrenOf = (name: string) => {
        children.value = route?.matched
            ?.find((r) => r.name === name)
            ?.children.filter((c) => c.alias);
    };

    return { children, getChildrenOf };
};
```

However, it isn't entirely accurate. For example, when declaring the children ref, it should be :

```
const children = ref([]);
```

But I get this error:

```
TS2322: Type 'RouteRecordRaw[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
```

Also, in the interface, I have to use `any` instead of the proper type of `[]` for the children property.

Please note, I'm very new to Typescript, so when I say 'proper' take it with a grain of salt.

Any way I can make this code better and not use catch all's like any?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ref is ultimately assigned to a subset of [`route.matched[].children`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/ebca15a/src/types/index.ts#L226), which is of type `RouteRecordRaw[]`.

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (in `route.matched.find(...)?.children`) short-circuits to `undefined`, so if `Array.prototype.find()` doesn't find a match, the ref type would be `undefined`. Otherwise, it would be `RouteRecordRaw[]`.

Therefore, the ref's `value` field is typed as `RouteRecordRaw[] | undefined`. Finally, the return value of `ref()` is of type `Ref<T>` (where `T` is the type of the argument to `ref()`), so the type of `children` is `Ref<RouteRecordRaw[] | undefined>`.

```js
import { ref, Ref } from "vue";
import { useRoute, RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";

interface RouterHelper {
                         
    children: Ref<RouteRecordRaw[] | undefined>;
    getChildrenOf: (name: string) => void;
}

export const routerHelper = (): RouterHelper => {
    const route = useRoute();
                             
    const children: RouterHelper['children'] = ref([]);

    const getChildrenOf = (name: string) => {
        children.value = route.matched
            .find((r) => r.name === name)
            ?.children.filter((c) => c.alias);
    };

    return { children, getChildrenOf };
};
```

Comment: I ended up changing the logic quite a bit, but that RouteRecordRaw still ended up helping so putting this as an answer.

Any chance you could explain the reasoning for this? If you have a `ref` always use  `Ref<something something>`?

Comment: @RizaKhan The return value of `ref()` is the generic `Ref<T>`. `T` can be inferred from primitive values (`string`s and `number`s), but not for complex types (object arrays in this case). See updated answer for how I arrived at the final type.